# Can't invoke HashMap's getEntry via reflection on Java 8

Tags: java, reflection, java-8

I have some legacy code (compiled and ran successfully with JDK 7u55) similar to the following:

```
private static class MyHashMap extends HashMap {
    static Method getEntryMethod;

    static {
        try {
            getEntryMethod = HashMap.class.getDeclaredMethod("getEntry", Object.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyHashMap myHashMap = new MyHashMap();
}
```

After trying to switch to JDK 8u31, it fails with:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.util.HashMap.getEntry(java.lang.Object)
```

Comment: No such method exists.  http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap

Comment: There is no public [`getEntry(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) method in `HashMap`.

Comment: Just to be curious, why are you doing this?

Comment: trying to fix some legacy code after updating jdk :)

Comment: see this qu. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395003/why-define-object-for-getentry-in-hashmap

Comment: but i think its not support with HashMap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like it was replaced with `getNode()`, which returns a `Node` (a different implementation of `Map.Entry<K,V>`). You'll have to change your code if you must use this method. There's a risk in using package private methods. They can disappear.

Comment: There is more than just the risk of disappearing. Even without the advent of a new version there might be alternative implementations not having that method *at the same time*. Oracle isn’t the only vendor of a JRE.

Comment: this was the problem thanks.
@Holger we bundle Oracle's jre so it's safe for now

Answer (score 5):

getEntry() was never part of the public API for the HashMap class. It looks like it's been changed in Java 8. This is why you should only ever rely on the published public API of classes.

Answer (score 1):

The method you are searching for is `final` and not `public`. In Java 8 it has been replaced/removed and since is not `public` it was not signed as `deprecated` and just removed.

```
/**
 * Returns the entry associated with the specified key in the
 * HashMap.  Returns null if the HashMap contains no mapping
 * for the key.
 */
final Entry<K,V> getEntry(Object key) {
    if (size == 0) {
        return null;
    }

    int hash = (key == null) ? 0 : hash(key);
    for (Entry<K,V> e = table[indexFor(hash, table.length)];
         e != null;
         e = e.next) {
        Object k;
        if (e.hash == hash &&
            ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
            return e;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Why on earth are you or who for you using reflection to get a `private` method to get an element from the `HashMap`? Use the plain and simple and public [`get(key)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) method instead.

Comment: Let's say I have a cache stored in a wrapped HashMap and an actual "MyHashMap" that has access to getEntry. 
The key element can have fields like "id" and "name", but the equals test is overridden by using only the "id" field. 

Try to add a new key with id=100 and name="aaa". Now, consider that there is a use-case where I try to add again an object with key id=100 and name="bbb". Using the HashMap's put method, the key's "name" field is not going to be updated to "bbb"

Comment: If I understood well you have a `key` object with two fields e.g. `Id, name` and you want that when another `key` with a different `name` but same `Id ` is added the key must not update. Why don't you use directly `Id` as your key and put the `name` value with the map `value`?

Comment: @AndreiMatei And btw, what does this have to do with reflection?

Comment: can't really redesign anything :)

Comment: Wouldn't it be vastly simpler to do a `remove` before every `put`, and avoid subclassing HashMap altogether?

Comment: There are other use-cases as well. Let's say we already have `key (id=1,name="aaa")` and I want to put a new `key (id=1, name=null)`. It will be fine, but then I need the key to be sent as a message to an event-dispatcher. I don't want to see a lot of "bla bla null null...."  I want to use the existing name from the old key, not null. I could iterate the entrySet and find it, but that's costly